# passing data of image to controller fails

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, html2canvas

I am making an Image from a div by html2canvas, then want to sent it back to controller. I set the result in input text file, to have the value in controller

I have this in client side:

```
var element = $("#chng");
     html2canvas(element,{
       onrendered : function(canvas){
           var imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
           var newData= imageData.replace(/^data:image\/jpg/, "data:application/octet-stream");
            $("#img1").val(newData);       
     
       }
   });
   $("#infoForm").submit();
```

and

```
  <form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Answers" id="infoForm">
        <input type="text" id="img1" name="img1" />
        <input type="button" onclick="formsubmit()" value="print PDF" />
   </form>
```

and controller

```
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PrintPDF(long wId, long cId, long pId, long aId, short no , string img1)
    {
       //but img1 is always null
       //ToDO something here

        return View();
       
    }
```

but img1 is always null although the value if newData and imageData in clientside are ok
what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `<form>` element in your HTML does not have an `asp-action` attribute specifying the action method that should be called when the form is submitted. This means that the form will not be submitted to the correct action method, and the img1 parameter will not be passed to the controller.

You can fix this issue by adding an `asp-action` attribute to the `<form>` element:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Answers" asp-action="PrintPDF" id="infoForm">
```

Secondly, the `onclick` attribute of the `<input>` element is calling a `formsubmit()` function, but there is no such function defined in your code. Therefore the form will not be submitted when the button is clicked, and the `img1` parameter will not be passed to the controller.

You can fix this issue by removing the `onclick` attribute from the`<input>` element, and calling the `submit()` method of the `infoForm` form in the JavaScript code:

```
var element = $("#chng");
html2canvas(element,{
   onrendered : function(canvas){
       var imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
       var newData= imageData.replace(/^data:image\/jpg/, "data:application/octet-stream");
        $("#img1").val(newData);       
 
       }
});
$("#infoForm").submit();
```

Third, the `enctype` attribute of the `<form>` element is set to `"multipart/form-data"`, but the `img1` parameter is not a file being uploaded. This can cause the `img1` parameter to be null in the controller, because the `multipart/form-data` encoding is not appropriate for non-file data.

You can fix this issue by changing the `enctype` attribute of the `<form>` element to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`:

```
<form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" asp-controller="Answers" asp-action="PrintPDF" id="infoForm">
```

Comment: it didn't work, I added another textbox for test, put some value in it. the test textbox has value in controller but not the img1 textbox

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the type? It is an octet stream you are trying to pass in, right? So why dont you use a byte array for `img1` and see how that works?